# Does Twig include a filter for auto-linking text?

Tags: symfony, twig

Symfony1 had a helper function called `auto_link_text()`, which parsed a block of text and wrapped all text URLs in `<a>` tags, automatically populating the `href` attribute.

Does Twig include a function like this? I've looked on Google, and gone through the code, but can't find one. I can obviously code one myself, but don't want to replicate something if it's already there.

If I do code one myself, should it be a function or a filter?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

the function doesn't exist in twig, but you can even add your own extensions to Twig :

```
class AutoLinkTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array('auto_link_text' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'auto_link_text', array('is_safe' => array('html'))),
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return "auto_link_twig_extension";
    }

    static public function auto_link_text($string)
    {

        $regexp = "/(<a.*?>)?(https?)?(:\/\/)?(\w+\.)?(\w+)\.(\w+)(<\/a.*?>)?/i";
        $anchorMarkup = "<a href=\"%s://%s\" target=\"_blank\" >%s</a>";

        preg_match_all($regexp, $string, $matches, \PREG_SET_ORDER);

        foreach ($matches as $match) {
            if (empty($match[1]) && empty($match[7])) {
                $http = $match[2]?$match[2]:'http';
                $replace = sprintf($anchorMarkup, $http, $match[0], $match[0]);
                $string = str_replace($match[0], $replace, $string);
            }
        }

        return $string;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution seems to work incorrectly for me if the URL already has a `http://` prefix. In that case, the resulting href will be something like `http://http://google.com`. What fixed it for me was replacing the third argument `$match[0]` to sprintf with `$match[4] . $match[5] . "." . $match[6]`.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using twig inside of Symfony2, there's a bundle for that: https://github.com/liip/LiipUrlAutoConverterBundle

If you're using it outside of Symfony2, you could submit a PR to them in order to decouple the bundle and the twig extension!

Answer (score 3):

The other listed "answer" is a little out of date and has issues. This one will work in the latest versions of Symfony and has less issues

```
class AutoLinkTwigExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return [new TwigFilter('auto_link', [$this, 'autoLink'], [
            'pre_escape'=>'html',
            'is_safe' => ['html']])];
    }

    static public function autoLink($string)
    {
        $pattern = "/http[s]?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9.\-\/?#=&]+/";
        $replacement = "<a href=\"$0\" target=\"_blank\">$0</a>";
        $string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
        return $string;
    }
}
```